# How to pass JSON data to public/javascripts/X.js in Node/Express?

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, express, ejs

I'm stuck on an Express project. Look here https://github.com/MoreeZ/help1 and look into `./public/javascripts/budget.js`. I want to swap the incomeData object so it reads data from ./incomedata.json

I tried passing it through the router but it only allowed me to read it through the .ejs files.

I want to be able to save and modify .json data received from my original JavaScript file through the JavaScript file.

If you want to see the final result https://moreez.github.io/MoreeZ/

Comment: Questions where the code is on a third-party site only are not on topic here. Would you post the `budget.js` file (or the relevant part of it) in the question itself? A formatting tool is provided. Links as a supplementary are OK, if you want.

Comment: Trying again to put this on hold.

Answer (score 1):

ES6 `imports` are not supported natively in all browsers.

You should use module loader library like [RequireJS](https://requirejs.org/), [Browserify](http://browserify.org/) or [Webpack](https://webpack.js.org/) to require external files into your front end javascript code.

If your goal is to read and modify the `.json` file , you need to implement end points in your server to writeFile/readFile and call them through network request from the front end code usually done by `ajax`.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I understand your problem but did you try to import the json file ?
like this :

`var your foo = require('./bar.json')`

In ES6:

`import foo from ('./bar.json')`

You can also probably use a node module like this one : [edit-json-file](https://www.npmjs.com/package/edit-json-file)

Comment: The problem is that I can't import it into my ./public/javascript/budget.js file becasue I get  "ReferenceError: require is not defined"